# Enviar audio a dispositivo Bluetooth C#

Tags: c#, bluetooth

¿En .Net no hay ninguna librería para poder enviar audio (enlazando antes con el dispositivo) por bluetooth?
Solo veo ejemplos para enlazar dispositivos y mandar archivos, telegramas etc... Pero no para hacer un Stream de audio...

Answer (score 0):

Por lo general he visto que se trabaja con la libreria `32feet`, pero esto NO es posible dentro de la biblioteca de `32feet.net`, solo puede configurar el dispositivo para hablar el servicio de audio de Microsoft utilizando la llamada al método [`setService`](http://www.nudoq.org/#!/Packages/32feet.NET/InTheHand.Net.Personal/MicrosoftSdpService/M/SetService) en `32feet.net`

Este servicio MS gestiona la salida `A2DP` al dispositivo. **No hay forma de enviar directamente audio desde el código al dispositivo Bluetooth usando esta biblioteca en C#**.

> Puede encontrar la especificación completa de `A2DP` en [este enlace](https://www.bluetooth.org/docman/handlers/DownloadDoc.ashx?doc_id=8236#page12)

Comment: Y de alguna manera se podría hacer lo que pido? Supongo que no será imposible... O quizás si :D

Comment: @Edulon me temo que no, al menos yo desconozco una opción, ojalá haya una manera :)